# Drawing a chessboard with Turtle (even number dimension fail)

Tags: python, python-3.x, loops, turtle-graphics, chess

I have written this Python code with turtle graphics for drawing a chessboard by given dimension. The problem I'm facing is when I enter an odd number everything works just fine:

[image]

- The last square is also filled, I just didn't manage to screen shot it on time

But when I enter an even number, it's like:

[image]

Here's the code:

```
from turtle import *
import sys


def main():
    dimension = int(input('Enter dimension: '))
    side = 50

    x_coord = -250
    y_coord = 300

    turtle = Turtle()
    turtle.speed('fastest')
    turtle.pensize(5)

    for i in range(dimension ** 2):
        if not i % dimension:
            y_coord -= side
            turtle.penup()
            turtle.setx(x_coord)
            turtle.sety(y_coord)
            turtle.pendown()

        if not i % 2:
            turtle.begin_fill()

        for _ in range(4):
            turtle.forward(side)
            turtle.right(90)

        turtle.forward(side)
        turtle.end_fill()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    sys.exit(main())
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A similar flag-based solution with alternate approaches.  I don't understand what your `main()` layout gets you so I reworked it to be a potential library with the test code under `__main__`:

```
import turtle

def draw_board(dimension, x_coord, y_coord, side):

    parity = False

    for i in range(dimension ** 2):
        if i % dimension == 0:
            y_coord -= side
            turtle.penup()
            turtle.setpos(x_coord, y_coord)
            turtle.pendown()
            parity = parity != (dimension % 2 == 0)  # logical XOR

        if parity:
            turtle.begin_fill()

        for _ in range(4):
            turtle.forward(side)
            turtle.right(90)

        if turtle.filling():
            turtle.end_fill()

        turtle.forward(side)

        parity = not parity


if __name__ == '__main__':
    size = int(input('Enter dimension: '))

    turtle.speed('fastest')

    turtle.pensize(5)

    draw_board(size, -250, 300, 50)

    turtle.hideturtle()

    turtle.exitonclick()
```

Answer (score 1):

I didnt look through your code, but it seems that the problem you have is that unlike a true chessboard, you change from white to black and vice versa when making a new line of squares, this example:

black,white,black,white
black,white,black,white
etc.

or black,white,black
   white,black,white
   etc.

while a chessboard is:

black,white,black,white
WHITE,black,white,black
BLACK....etc.

you see the difference?

so that seems to be the problem, il try to fix your code aswell, but i think you could manage that

Answer (score 1):

I suggest setting a flag for when to fill instead of doing it only when it's an odd number from the range which is what trips you up since it doesn't go black white left to right, it reaches then end an then goes right to left.

Anyway, here is my edit, just a simple boolean which toggles each time except when going to new row. I also suggest using `turtle.exitonclick` instead of `sys.exit`

```
from turtle import *

def main():
    dimension = int(input('Enter dimension: '))
    side = 50

    x_coord = -250
    y_coord = 300

    turtle = Turtle()
    turtle.speed('fastest')
    turtle.pensize(5)

    fill = False

    for i in range(dimension ** 2):
        if not i % dimension:
            y_coord -= side
            turtle.penup()
            turtle.setx(x_coord)
            turtle.sety(y_coord)
            turtle.pendown()
            if not dimension % 2:
                fill = not fill

        if fill:
            turtle.begin_fill()

        for _ in range(4):
            turtle.forward(side)
            turtle.right(90)

        turtle.forward(side)
        turtle.end_fill()
        fill = not fill

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
    exitonclick()
```

Answer (score 0):

For Python 3,7 I would recommend this way

```
import turtle

turtle.speed(0)
turtle.up()
turtle.goto(-200,200)
turtle.down()

for row in range(8):

    for col in range(8):
        if col % 2 == row % 2:
            turtle.forward(50)
            continue
        turtle.begin_fill()

        for _ in range(4):
            turtle.forward(50)
            turtle.right(90)
        turtle.end_fill()
        turtle.forward(50)
    turtle.backward(400)
    turtle.right(90)
    turtle.forward(50)
    turtle.left(90)

turtle.width(6)

for _ in range(4):
    turtle.forward(400)
    turtle.left(90)

turtle.hideturtle()
turtle.done()
```

Comment: The OP's issue was drawing a generalized checker pattern of variable dimension that worked fine for odd sizes (a 9 x 9 is shown) but not for even.  This only works for *one* size (8 x 8).